# Other layout for scaffolding

Tags: cakephp, layout, scaffolding

My default layout is default.ctp, but I want to use another layout default-scaffolds.ctp only for scaffolding views, when I use in the controller:

```
public $scaffold;
```

I tried in the AppController

```
    public function beforeScaffold() {
        $this->layout = 'default-scaffolds';
}
```

but that didn't work.

I appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this `beforeRender()`

```
public function beforeRender() {
    if (in_array($this->request->action, array('index', 'add', 'view', 'edit'))) {
        $this->layout = 'default-scaffolds';
    }
}
```

Comment: that works for me only when the actions (index, add, view, edit) exist and when the views exist. But what i want is use it with
    public $scaffold;

Answer (score 3):

I was just facing the same problem and solved it by specifying router prefix 'admin', setting up

```
public $scaffold = 'admin';
```

in the controller and in the AppController I added to the beforeFilter() method

```
public function beforeFilter() {
  if ($this->request->prefix == 'admin') {
    $this->layout = 'scaffold';
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, in lib/Cake/Controller/Scaffold.php, in line 377 (the `_scaffold(CakeRequest $request)`-function, within this if: `if (in_array($request->params['action'], $this->scaffoldActions))`, just add the following line:

```
$this->layout = 'default_scaffold'; // this is a custom-added line in order to activate the default CSS file when scaffolding
```

And add default_scaffold.ctp to your Layout folder.